# Security issue with default Postfix's "Internet Site" settings

Tags: 12.04, email, postfix, smtp, sendmail

I want to install Postfix to send out email from localhost or/and relay email to external mail gateway (e.g. sendgrid). However, **I do not want to receive mail** using this machine, and I don't want to accept connection from other machines.

When installing Postfix, the default is "Internet Site", this configuration did works perfectly for my purpose. But my understanding is with this setting, my Postfix can also receive mail.

So what should I do in order to disable the un-needed features, any best practice for Postfix configuration for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding security, since you need to relay for your internal clients you must allow Postfix to receive mail. You set the:

```
mynetworks_style = subnet
```

in `main.cf` and no host outside your subnet can use your Postfix as a transport thus you don't receive any mail from outside. Mynetworks_style also has a `class` option where you can define a subnet class in the form of

```
mynetworks = x.x.x.x/y  p.p.p.p/q
```

for allowed hosts.

It's technically possible to send mail thru Gmail etc. but I don't think free email services allow this. This is what I have done for Gmail:

In `main.cf` add:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain     = $mydomain
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
```

In my case `$mydomain` is there because my LAN domain is the same as my Google Apps domain. You will probably need to add `gmail.com` or literal Google Apps domain name if that's not the case with you.

You also need to create a hash for the user:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 user@example.org:s3cr3+pA55
```

Where `user@example.com` is your FQ username, and `s3cr3+pA55` is your actual password in plaintext. You place that contint in `/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd` and generate a hash by doing:

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
```

Finally, do note that even tho I've sent mail only to my own domain users, Google has blocked my sender username after a while and refuse to do anything about it. As it appears, automatic sending of mail (in my case server notifications) through their servers is forbidden tho it's hard to decypher that from their terms.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to setup Postfix as a "Satellite system" instead of an "Internet site."

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

"**Satellite system**: All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for delivery."

dpkg-reconfigure will walk you through the configuration and update /etc/postfix/main.cf accordingly.

The smarthost would be your external mail gateway. You need to make sure that is set to accept mail from this satellite system. (For a Postfix external mail g, that would mean adding the Satellite system to mynetworks on the smarthost.)

Comment: I want to send email, e.g. gmail, hotmail, yahoo, but not using smtp relay

Comment: ... do you want to send email using SMTP at all? Do you mean Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo! through webmail, or a mail client like Thunderbird? You don't need Postfix for that... and, you can't really use Postfix to send out authorized email from a Gmail address, unless maybe you can authenticate with Gmail's SMTP servers... Is that what you were doing as an "Internet Site"? Are you sure you need Postfix?

Comment: Basically I want postfix to send out email from localhost but ignore incoming emails from any hosts